# Dynamic object Handling in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am facing issue while clicking on dynamic object.I have one link object with below format :  123456789 B &[L]
Here value 123456789 getting from excel sheet and B is dynamic value which is may be vary from A to Z.
I'm able to click on Link object using regular expression but it is taking huge time to click and getting error 'Object description is mismatch' in report.

```
Browser("ABC").Page("CBD").Frame("TRIP").Link("123456789 B& [L]").Click
```

Could you please help me to handle this case in UFT.

Answer (score 1):

For the dynamically changing property of that link, you can use the regular expression(in the OR):

```
123456789 [A-Z]& \[L\]
```

**[Click for Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gy4I3N/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `123456789` - matches `123456789`
- - matches a space
- `[A-Z]` - matches a single occurrence of a capital letter
- `&` - matches a `&`
- - matches a space
- `\[L\]` - matches a `[` followed by `L` followed by `]`

**Update**

In case the digits are also not constant, you can use the regex `[0-9]+ [A-Z]& \[L\]`. Check [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gy4I3N/2) here.

Comment: 123456789 also dynamic value but this is getting from excel sheet so How I can use regular expression here.I am using \d any digit for this object but system taking huge time to click on that link.Please suggest

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply!! Able to click on link element using [0-9]+ [A-Z]& \[L\] but problem is that still taking 10-15 seconds to click on that element.

Comment: Is smart identification turned on? If yes, turn it off. Also, it would be a bit more helpful if you post an image displaying how you have set the refular expression in the property stored in OR